# .net alternative to glassfish

Tags: glassfish

i am a fan of GlassFish but no knowlegde of JAVA nor a desie to learn any.  Does anybody know a platform (open source) like GlassFish but on the .net stack ?
http://glassfish.java.net/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Apache?  You can run ASP.NET code off Apache using mod_mono

See [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono) for specifics.  There is also the [Cassini](http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/) server as well...

Comment: not the point.  Its not a matter of running asp.net on linux.  Its the fact that GlassFish has to be coded in Java, so need like product ..